# Is there any way for use Azure Maps as Map Server like Geoserver, QGIS Server, ...?

Tags: azure, shapefile, qgis, wms, azure-maps

I need to use a map server for requesting geoinformation like GetFeatureInfo/GetCapabilities/...
and obtain all layers' information. The layers are WMS and Shapefile.

My question is if I could use Azure Maps as geo server or if Azure has any similar product that belongs to Azure.

Answer (score 0):

Azure Maps doesn't currently provide a full map server for custom data. There is the Azure Maps Creator platform, however that is currently limited to indoor map data via DWG files.

That said, Azure Maps does support connecting to WMS services and there are samples for overlaying Shapefiles on the map directly:

https://azuremapscodesamples.azurewebsites.net/?search=WMS

https://azuremapscodesamples.azurewebsites.net/?search=shapefile